# Why does this array print "array" instead of a value? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays, web

I'm learning PHP and doing a basic eCommerce shopping cart for practice. I came across an issue that's stumped me. I made an array to display the current amount of a single item the shopper has in their cart, but rather than displaying the value it displays "array."

Below is what I'm using:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['Cart'])){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM products where Product_ID IN (";

    foreach($_SESSION['Cart'] as $id => $value){

        $sql.=$id.",";
        }
        $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY Category ASC";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        ?>
            <p><?php echo $row['Name']?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']] ?></p>
        <?php
        }
}else{

    echo "<p>There are no products selected</p>";
}
?>
```

I'm not sure if that's where the exact issue is though. The rest of my site is sourced [here](http://pastebin.com/cRsJU56a)(Index) and [here](http://pastebin.com/yjnv00aV)(Product page) if anyone would be so kind as to troubleshoot with me.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @user3807604 Do a `print_r()` instead of `echo` on the variable that is printing out 'Array'. to see the structure of the array. you would know what to do from there.
E.g: `print_r($_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']])`

Comment: Don't forget to put the key at the end of the array, for instance `$arr[0]` or `$arr['quantity']`

Comment: @Rybo111 When printing, I get something like the following:
Orange Juice x Array ( [quantity] => 1 )

The name (Orange Juice) displays correctly, and it is counting the quantity, but it still echo's as Orange Juice x Array if I switch it back to echo from print. Why won't it just display the quantity that it's keeping track of?

Comment: Whatever you array is, you need to do as @RaymondAtivie has said and `print_r` it. This will give you the key to value association. You then need to add `['key_here']` to the end of the variable that you are trying to echo.

Comment: @user3807604 if you try `$_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity]` it should work based on your feedback. But ii think your real problem is from when you assign values to the array

Comment: Alright, I was able to tackle the issue with your help guys. Printing the array to break it down more really gave me a wonderful troubleshooting start, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your feedback
if trying `print_r($_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity])` gives you `Array ( [quantity] => 1 )`

Then you can echo `$_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity]` to give you `1`

But i don't think this was the original intention. 
i think your real problem is from when you assign values to the array, there is a possible mismatching of keys.

Try the code above and lets know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with this line of code:

```
$_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]
```

You are getting a value from `$_SESSION['Cart']` with a dimensional array of `$row` there. I think `$row['Product_ID']` is not an array but instead a `string` or `int` so calling `$row['Product_ID']['quantity']` is an issue.